# How configured contact form for sending email

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I request your kind help with this problem. I have a website with the respective contact form, but it has never worked for me. The messages do not arrive. Sending them the contact page `send_mail.php` file and everything related. I thank you very much the help and detailed explanation as this topic is very complex.

**Contact.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#send_message').click(function(e){

                //stop the form from being submitted
                e.preventDefault();

                /* declare the variables, var error is the variable that we use on the end
                to determine if there was an error or not */
                var error = false;
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var subject = $('#subject').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();

                /* in the next section we do the checking by using VARIABLE.length
                where VARIABLE is the variable we are checking (like name, email),
                length is a javascript function to get the number of characters.
                And as you can see if the num of characters is 0 we set the error
                variable to true and show the name_error div with the fadeIn effect. 
                if it's not 0 then we fadeOut the div( that's if the div is shown and
                the error is fixed it fadesOut. 

                The only difference from these checks is the email checking, we have
                email.indexOf('@') which checks if there is @ in the email input field.
                This javascript function will return -1 if no occurence have been found.*/
                if(name.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(subject.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#subject_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#subject_error').fadeOut(500);
                }
                if(message.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
                }

                //now when the validation is done we check if the error variable is false (no errors)
                if(error == false){
                    //disable the submit button to avoid spamming
                    //and change the button text to Sending...
                    $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });

                        /* using the jquery's post(ajax) function and a lifesaver
                        function serialize() which gets all the data from the form
                        we submit it to send_email.php */
                    $.post("send_email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                        //and after the ajax request ends we check the text returned
                        if(result == 'sent'){
                            //if the mail is sent remove the submit paragraph
                             $('#button').remove();
                            //and show the mail success div with fadeIn
                            $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                        }else{
                            //show the mail failed div
                            $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                            //reenable the submit button by removing attribute disabled and change the text back to Send The Message
                            $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Submit');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });    
        });
```

**Send_mail.php**

```
    require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

    $name     =   $_POST['name'];  
    $email    =   $_POST['email'];
    $subject  =   $_POST['subject'];
    $message  =   $_POST['message'];
    $message_body = "...";
    $mail_options =[;
            "sender" => "administrador@formarchivos.com",
        "to" => $email,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "textBody" => $message_body
    ];

    try {
            $message = new Message($mail_options);
            $message->send();
            echo 'sent';

} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo 'failed';
}
```

**Contact.html**

```
    <!-- Contact Form -->
    <form action="send_email.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
      <h3>Ficha de contacto</h3>
      <div class="hr dotted clearfix">
        <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="clearfix">
          <h3>
            <label for="name">Nombre</label>
            <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
          </h3>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <h3 id='name_error' class='error'>Inserte un nombre</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
          <h3>
            <label for="email">Email </label>
            <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
          </h3>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <h3 id='email_error' class='error'>Ingrese una cuenta de correo valida</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
          <h3>
            <label for="subject">Tema</label>
            <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' />
          </h3>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <h3 id='subject_error' class='error'>Ingrese un Tema para su mensaje</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
          <h3>
            <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea name='message' id='message' rows="30" cols="30"></textarea>
          </h3>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <h3 id='message_error' class='error'>Ingrese su mensaje</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
          <h3 id='mail_success' class='success'>Gracias. Nosotros te responderemos tan pronto como nos sea posible.</h3>
          <h3 id='mail_fail' class='error'>Disculpenos, un error ha ocurrido. Por favor intentelo despues.</h3>
          <div id="button">
            <h3>
              <input type='submit' id='send_message' class="button" value='Enviar' />
            </h3>
          </div>
          <!--end wrapper-->
<div align=center></div></body>
</html>
```

This is all that I have, I have nothing `mensaje.php`, if I may not need any extra file to be honest I do not know where can be the error.

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in your php file. If I am not mistaken, there shouldn't be any semicolon in the following line: `$mail_options =[;`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your syntax error suggested by @koljanep I have a couple suggestions/comments:

1. Have you tried doing a function (perhaps even on the `php` page) to handle your
   jQuery errors instead of repeating a bunch of same fade effects?
2. Maybe sanitize your inputs on the `PHP` page.
3. Perhaps a more straight-forward `AJAX` would help.
4. You assign
   `$message = $_POST['message'];` but then you assign `$message = new
   Message($mail_options);` so there is some weirdness going on
   there...

**Contact.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#contact_form').submit(function(e){
                $.ajax({
                        url:"Send_mail.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $("#send_message").serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                                // This id would have to be somewhere on your page
                                // to drop into (I'm sure you know that)
                                $("#response").html(data);
                            }
                    });

                return false;
            });    
        });
```

**Send_mail.php**

```
<?php
    // Do some basic sanitizing...I chose preg_replace, but you can do whatever
    $setting['name']    =   (!empty($_POST['name']))? preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\']/'," ",$_POST['name']):0;
    $setting['subject'] =   (!empty($_POST['subject']))? preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\']/'," ",$_POST['subject']):0;
    $setting['message'] =   (!empty($_POST['message']))? strip_tags($_POST['message']):0;

    // Check first that the email is a valid one!
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // If all checks out, 
            if(!in_array(0,$setting)) {
                    require_once('google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php');
                    use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

                    $name           =   $_POST['name'];  
                    $email          =   $_POST['email'];
                    $subject        =   $_POST['subject'];
                    $message        =   $_POST['message'];
                    $message_body   =   "...";
                    $mail_options   =   [
                                            "sender" => "administrador@formarchivos.com",
                                            "to" => $email,
                                            "subject" => $subject,
                                            "textBody" => $message.$message_body
                                        ];

                    try {
                            $sendMessage = new Message($mail_options);
                            $sendMessage->send();
                            echo 'sent';
                        }
                    catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            echo 'failed';
                        }
                }
            else 
                $_error =   $setting;
        }
    else {
            $setting['email']   =   0;
            $_error             =   $setting;
        } ?>

<script>
    function ReturnError(IdVal) {
            $('#'+IdVal+"_error").fadeIn(500);
        }
<?php
    if(isset($_error)) {
            foreach($_error as $key => $errored) {
                    if($errored == 0) { ?>
    ReturnError('<?php echo $key; ?>');
                <?php }
                }
        } ?>
</script>
```